# How can attach a backup policy to a VM?

Tags: azure, terraform

I have a question with azurerm provider for terraform:

You have the following resources:

```
azurerm_recovery_services_vault
azurerm_backup_policy_vm
```

In order to create a policy and vault for backup a machine.

But how you can attach this policy to a machine ?

In other versions you have the following resource

```
azurerm_recovery_services_protected_vm
```

But this resource is not recognized on azurerm 2.36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource for attach is azurerm_backup_protected_vm

Comment: Welcome on the ServerFault! Please give more details, your post need to answer the question (on the top).